CORS issue with Vue frontend and Node.js backend across different domains—works after only supervisor restart
I have a messenger where the frontend is built with Vue.js and the backend with Node.js. Both are hosted on different domains, and CORS is configured to allow cross-domain communication. It works, but sometimes there's an issue with CORS. It can work normally, but after 2 hours, it stops working due to a CORS error.
The OPTIONS preflight request  returns a 204 No Content, which seems correct. However, the actual HTTP POST login request fails with a 524 error. Restarting the supervisor on the Node.js backend consistently resolves the issue temporarily. Changing browsers doesn’t help, and clearing the Cloudflare cache when it's not working also doesn’t resolve the issue. 
